# C# updating with table adapter auto increments in my database

Tags: c#, database, winforms, datagridview

I've setup a datagridview where I load some values in from a cvs file that looks like this:

```
ID         NAME
 1         John
 2         Who
18         Test
```

So now that my values are in the datagridview I just use the following code to update it to my database:

```
_docentTableAdapter.Update(final.docent);
```

But when I check my database afterwards I get:

```
ID         NAME
 1         John
 2         Who
 3         Test
```

It seems like it just appends itself and ignoring the ID. How can I get it to use the ID that I supplied rather then auto incrementing itself?

Thanks

EDIT:
I'm using a MySql database, the _docentTableAdapter comes from my typed dataset. In my typed dataset I have a table named "docent" and in that table 2 columns: ID and name. The ID is the primary key and I've set auto increment to false in my typed dataset.

Comment: Well, your database more than likely is set to auto increment.  Also is your insert query passing an `Id` or are you using the default key column?

Comment: what technologies do you use? SQL, EF, nHibernate? what is `_docentTableAdapter`? It matters because answer depends on this

Comment: for make your own ids in your table in youre using SQL have configurate the table with no autoincrement or Identity 0, now for match the ids from your datagridview have to make by your own code logic

Comment: update and Inserts are 2 totally different things ..I would not remove the auto incrementing I would however separate and or refactor how I am doing updates vs Inserts.. separate the code out into 2 simple methods one to call the insert.. the other to call the update.

Comment: Afaik, MySQL dont make you to turn AutoIncrement if you want to specify Identity. You just have to explicitly insert data with identity mentioned. It is AutoIncremented only if you omit identity. Back to OP's problem, you need to check your Insert implementation (not sure about UPDATING identity) and specify Identity you want to be inserted in DataBase